# GUI framework taking too much GPU power

Tags: c++, user-interface, gpu

I am using TGUI framework which is developed over SFML for C++ for GUI. Recently i had created a GUI application using TGUI, the problem with this application is that it is consuming too much GPU power almost 60% every time I use it, this GPU power is too much for a simple application.
I am not able to figure out why is it using too much GPU.
I checked some other GUI applications they don't consume any GPU.
is the problem with TGUI framework or is it something I am missing?
Thank you.

A minimal example of the main loop of application is:

```
while (window.isOpen())

    {
       sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // When the window is closed, the application ends
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();

            // When the window is resized, the view is changed
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
            {
                window.setView(sf::View(sf::FloatRect(0.f, 0.f, static_cast<float>(event.size.width), static_cast<float>(event.size.height))));
                gui.setView(window.getView());
            }

            // Pass the event to all the widgets
            gui.handleEvent(event);
        }

        window.clear();

        // Draw all created widgets
        gui.draw();

        window.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Have you reduced your program to the smallest form that shows this behaviour? In other words... do you have a [mre]?

Comment: It sounds like an immediate-mode GUI, which constantly re-renders itself in a loop. If the high GPU usage is a problem, you need to look for a different GUI framework.

Comment: It looks like you are rendering in a tight loop. That code will eat as many resources as possible. Typically you would aim at 60FPS. In a basic setup that means that you need to measure time between frames and sleep between iterations.

Comment: yes the problem was that the frameRateLimit was not set, so the rendering loop was rendering graphics at hundreds of FPS. now its solved thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the rendering loop, with no FPS set the loop had no delay and hence it was rendering at hundred's of FPS. I just had to set a frame rate limit.